Proper way to handle SQL errors in anorm?
I see that executeQuery returns a SqlQueryResult, which has a statementWarning() that returns Option[SQLWarning].
Is this the only place I should check to see whether my insert failed? The doc mentions exceptions in some places (such as UnexpectedNullableFound) but I don't think they apply here. Just want to confirm.

Okay, I see that "executeQuery" works only for queries, and not for inserts. So it seems like an exception is the only way I can know whether it failed? I may have misunderstood the claim "you don’t need to bother with exceptions" in the doc.

Digging through the code, I see an AnormException. Perhaps that's what I should be expecting? It would be super cool if that was documented.
